# WEBP sequence or WEBM file scrub on mouseover?

Tags: html5-video, webp, webm

Would you know if WEBP sequence with alpha or WEBM movie with alpha can be made scrubbable when the mouse is hovering over the image horizontally, otherwise it should be still?

Similar to how the GIFs are realized in [SketchFab](https://www.SketchFab.com)'s front page if you scroll down to this section:

[image]

Here's my files to test that with:

WEBP sequence with ALPHA (5MB):
https://manujarvinen.com/webm-test/redish_turnaround.webp

WEBM movie with ALPHA, keyframe on every frame (4MB):
https://manujarvinen.com/webm-test/redish_turnaround.webm

Comment: The site uses **sprites** as frames in a [tile map](https://media.sketchfab.com/models/3024378625f0426781910a286ff9facc/fallbacks/83e394f7bc724c1e94e684c45cd6023d/162d90f500f84ac1b4a660016dd1c347.jpeg). It is not a video and is not a sequence of image files. So the final "video" effect is from showing small sections of one jpeg image (each section is a "frame" of video to scrub to)

Comment: @VC.One Haa, handy! That could be the most optimal way of handling this. Except I need the alpha transparency.